# How to render custom generated ruleset in styled-jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, next.js, styled-jsx

### TL;DR

**How does one insert a variable that contains one or more CSS rules into styled-jsx** (using styled-jsx-plugin-sass under the hood)?

---

I have the following JSX style:

```
// src/pages/index.tsx
...
<style jsx>
  {`
    .test {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      background-color: green;
      ${contained}
     }
  `}
</style>
```

And `contained` is a variable that I'm trying to insert into it the mentioned rule:

```
// src/styles/break.ts

export const contained = `
margin: 0 auto;
${breakAt("sm")(`
  width: calc(100% - 10vw);
`)}
${breakAt("md")(`
  width: calc(100% - 15vw);
`)}
@media screen and (min-width: calc(960px + 10vw)) {
  width: 960px;
}`;
...
```

---

Notes:

> `breakAt` is a function that generates a specific media query `(breakpoint: string) => (content: string) => string`
>
> I have ensured that `styled-jsx-plugin-sass` is configured correctly - writing the generated CSS in raw acts as intended.
>
> I've also looked into how I believe styled-jsx behaves - it seems to do some literal parsing of the code I put in as I wrote a generator (`(content: string) => string` acting on `contained`) and called it, and the parser recognised that I wrote a `CallExpression`, but failed to render anything because of that.
>
> I understand that this could be solved using `@mixin/@include` but I'm picking and choosing features of Sass that I like at this point (mainly embedded rules), and was curious to see what was possible.

Your input and correction is greatly appreciated. **Please read the full question before answering!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a fan of `styled-components` (yet!) but it seems to be the valid situation in this scenario:

```
import styled from "styled-components"
// ... other imports

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  /* ... scoped styles */
  ${contained} /* mixin */
`

export default SomeComponent({ children }) {
  return <Wrapper>This component was mixed in<Wrapper/>
}
```